# SAS concatenate in SAS Data Step

Tags: sas

I don't know how to describe this question but here is an example. I have an initial dataset looks like this:

```
input  first second $3.;
cards;
1 A
1 B
1 C
1 D
2 E
2 F
3 S
3 A
4 C
5 Y
6 II
6 UU
6 OO
6 N
7 G
7 H
...
;
```

I want an output dataset like this:

```
input  first second $;
cards;
1 "A,B,C,D"
2 "E,F"
3 "S,A"
4 "C"
5 "Y"
6 "II,UU,OO,N"
7 "G,H"
...
;
```

Both tables will have two columns. Unique value of range of the column "first" could be 1 to any number.

Can someone help me ?

Comment: See an example here and you can use the `QUOTE()` function to add the quotes afterwards if you really need it. https://gist.github.com/statgeek/d583cfa992bf56da51d435165b07e96a

Comment: I thought this would be a duplicate question for sure but I can't find any good dupes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like below

```
 proc sort data=have;
 by first second;
 run;
data want(rename=(b=second));
 length new_second $50.;
do until(last.first);
set have;
by first second ;
new_second =catx(',', new_second, second);
b=quote(strip(new_second));
end;
drop second new_second;
run;
```

output is

```
 first  second
 1         "A,B,C,D"
 2         "E,F"
 3          "A,S"
 4           "C"
 5          "Y"
 6         "II,N,OO,UU"
 7         "G,H"
```

Comment: Did you run this?  It does not give the expected output.  Also contains warnings in the log and contains extraneous code.

Comment: @robert you are right, it was wrong. corrected it now. Thanks for correcting me

Answer (score 1):

You can use by-group processing and the retain function to achieve this.

Create a sample dataset:

```
data have;
input id value $3.;
cards;
1 A
1 B
1 C
1 D
2 E
2 F
3 S
3 A
4 C
5 Y
6 II
6 UU
6 OO
6 N
7 G
7 H
;
run;
```

First ensure that your dataset is sorted by your id variable:

```
proc sort data=have;
  by id;
run;
```

Then use the `first.` and `last.` notation to identify when the id variable is changing or about to change.  The `retain` statement tells the datastep to keep the value within `concatenated_value` over observations rather than resetting it to a blank value.  Use the `quote()` function to apply the `"` chars around the result before outputting the record.  Use the `cats()` function to perform the actual concatenation and separate the records with a `,`.

```
data want;
  length contatenated_value $500.;
  set have;
  by id;
  retain contatenated_value ;

  if first.id then do;
    contatenated_value = '';
  end;

  contatenated_value = catx(',', contatenated_value, value);

  if last.id then do;
    contatenated_value = quote(cats(contatenated_value));
    output;
  end;

  drop value;
run;
```

Output:

```
contatenated_
    value        id

"A,B,C,D"         1
"E,F"             2
"S,A"             3
"C"               4
"Y"               5
"II,UU,OO,N"      6
"G,H"             7
```