# In SAS, how to concatenate multiple rows into 1 by some ID

Tags: merge, sas, concatenation, string-concatenation, retain

I have a table like this

```
org_ID          linenr  text
811558672   10  Legevirksomhet.
811560782   10  Clavier Classics er et musikkselskap som produserer komposisjoner og
811560782   20  arrangementer av svÃ¦rt hÃ¸y kvalitet. De kombinerer den klassiske
811560782   30  musikktradisjonen med moderne teknikker og deres kunder spenner fra
811560782   40  individuelle musikere til ensembler, festivalarrangÃ¸rer, konserthus,
811560782   50  kulturinstitusjoner, eventskapere og mediaprodusenter.
811560812   10  Grafisk design, illustrasjon og nÃ¦rliggende virksomhet.
811561592   10  Sosial- og helsetjenesten. Konsulentvirksomhet: Veiledning til
811561592   20  foreldre, fosterhjem, skole og barnehage.
```

As you can see, for some org_ID, they appear multiple times because one line of text is not enough for them. When this happens, the linenr shows multiple numbers. Now I want to concatenate multiple lines of text into one when org_ID is the same. How shall I do this? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SAS concatenate in SAS Data Step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50051737/sas-concatenate-in-sas-data-step)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SAS `Retain` functionality to concatenate the text and only output when an new org_ID is read.

Note: The two IF statements handles the cases of first row and last row; where there is no Previous  ID or no Next ID.

Working Code: (Your Input data must be sorted)

```
data have;
infile datalines dlm=',' dsd; 
length org_ID 8.  linenr 8. text $200.;
input org_ID linenr  text $;
datalines;
811558672,10, "Legevirksomhet."
811560782,10, "Clavier Classics er et musikkselskap som produserer komposisjoner og"
811560782,20, "arrangementer av svÃ¦rt hÃ¸y kvalitet. De kombinerer den klassiske"
811560782,30, "musikktradisjonen med moderne teknikker og deres kunder spenner fra"
811560782,40, "individuelle musikere til ensembler, festivalarrangÃ¸rer, konserthus,"
811560782,50, "kulturinstitusjoner, eventskapere og mediaprodusenter."
811560812,10, "Grafisk design, illustrasjon og nÃ¦rliggende virksomhet."
811561592,10, "Sosial- og helsetjenesten. Konsulentvirksomhet: Veiledning til"
811561592,20, "foreldre, fosterhjem, skole og barnehage."
;
run;

data want;
set have nobs=nobs;
retain longtext;
retain id;
if(_N_=1) then do; longtext=text; id=org_ID; end;
else if org_ID ne id then do; output; longtext=text; id=org_ID; end;
else longtext=cats(longtext,text);
if (_N_=nobs) then do; output; end;
keep org_ID longtext;
run;
```

Output:

```
org_ID=811560782 longtext=Legevirksomhet.
org_ID=811560812 longtext=Clavier Classics er et musikkselskap som produserer komposisjoner ogarrangementer av svÃ¦rt hÃ¸y kva
org_ID=811561592 longtext=Grafisk design, illustrasjon og nÃ¦rliggende virksomhet.
org_ID=811561592 longtext=Sosial- og helsetjenesten. Konsulentvirksomhet: Veiledning tilforeldre, fosterhjem, skole og barneha
```

Answer (score 1):

A DOW loop can accumulate each line of text in the org_ID group into a final longtext.  The longtext should be assigned a specific length in order to prevent truncations that may occur if default lengths are used.  You may or may not want a space separator between lines that are concatenated.

```
data want(keep=org_ID longtext);
  do until (last.org_ID);
    set have;
    by org_ID;
    length longtext $2000;
    longtext = catx(' ', longtext, text);
  end;
run;
```

If the data is not sorted, but the org_ID rows are contiguous, you can use

```
    by org_ID notsorted;
```

So what is happening ?

- Longtext is a non dataset variable, so it is automatically reset to missing at the top of the data step.
- The data step iterates for each row in the group until the last row in the group.
- The length of the variable `longtext` is specified after the set statement so it be the last variable in program data vector (pdv), and thus be the second column of the kept variables.
- `catx` is used accumulate the concatenations of the text data within the group.  A space is used to separate the text data parts.

If you do not want the space separator, accumulate using

```
    longtext = cats(longtext, text);
```